# Capture IPython output in a Python Kernel

Tags: python, ipython, stringio, cstringio

I want to capture the output produced by IPython terminal in a Python terminal.
As all the testing takes place using a Python Kernel.
I know about the IPython magic function.
%%capture 
Is there a way to use these magic functions as context manager and capture the output, or maybe some other way?

Thanks.

Comment: "I want to capture the output produced by IPython terminal in a Python terminal." I don't understand what you are trying to achieve exactly. Can you please add more details about what exactly you are doing / trying to accomplish?

Comment: To be concise, something like   </br>

%%capture cap  </br>
print abc  </br>

Captures the stderr but,</br>

captures the stderr, while</br>

from IPython.utils import capture</br>  
with capture.capture_output() as cap: </br> 
    print xyz  </br>

does not capture the error, what am I doing wrong?